# Is that possible install rancher HA without any public domain (--set hostname)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

Install Rancher 2.x HA cluster flow the [offical document](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/ha/helm-rancher/). But I can't install it without public DNS - hostname. Is there any way to avoid this? I try to use /etc/hosts file but it seems like there an issue with agent docker doesn't get config from custom DNS.
I want to access the load-balancing cluster via IP, not via public DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, in a standard installation of Kubernetes, access to the API is done in HTTPS, and you need a certificate.

You can have a look at this doc: [Controlling Access to the Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/).

If your goal is just running a lab, maybe you can use [xip.io](http://xip.io/) if you do not have a DNS server on which you have the hand.

Comment: A certificate can be obtained and used without having a hostname, this is not answering the question.

Comment: Xip.io DNS resolution not working anymore - https://forums.rancher.com/t/xip-io-dns-resolution-not-working-anymore/20550/1